# How do I customize my ActionBar?

Tags: android

I am using android studio, with design library. The problem is, stock `actionbar` does not come with `edittext`, so I wanted to add my own. I tried this code, but it is force closing.

```
 //support lib
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    //
   //custom ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
    EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(
            R.id.searchfield);
    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                      KeyEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

**custom actionbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textFilter" 
    android:text="Text">

</EditText>
```

**logs**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rsoft.clipsearch/rsoft.clipsearch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(int)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toolbar with custom UI like this

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textFilter" 
                    android:text="Text"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
         </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting custom `view` to `ActionBar`, you can you custom `Toolbar`.

**1.** Add below custom `Toolbar` layout into your `activity` layout `XML`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchfield"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textFilter"
            android:text="Text"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**2.** In your `MainActivity`, set this `Toolbar` to work as support `ActionBar`.

```
// Custom toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

EditText search = (EditText) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }
});

if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**3.** Use below `theme` to your `MainActivity`.

```
//styles.xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>

//AndroidManifest.xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    ...........
    ...............
</activity>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: do you work for NASA ? because your code is crashing before taking off :D

Comment: `                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rsoft.a445455/rsoft.a445455.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView$OnEditorActionListener)' on a null object reference
`

Comment: I have used this same code and its working fine and for confirmation i have attached image. Check your layout and java code

Comment: FYI, I am not a photo-shop guy and not working in NASA. Just to help you i tried in my pc and when it works then i gave it in answer. Hope you understand :)

Comment: can you please share your latest xml and java code?

Comment: Check my 1st point, replace your current Toolbar xml with my Toolbar that contains EditText. and follow point 2 and 3. Definitely it should work :)